# VBA: range selection

Tags: vba, range

I would like to ask, if I need to select an entire row, start from the 3rd row as a range in VBA, instead of the below line, any better ways to go about it? Many thanks.

```
Range("C3:C1048576").Select
```

Comment: There is obviously more to this then what is presented here.  To answer this question, to "select" ([which should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)) all rows below 2nd row in a column, the method you are using is the best.  Now if you want to also find the last cell with a value see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba). Then you can limit it to just the data.

Comment: That's the 3rd **column**. If you want to make it work in any version of Excel, you'll use something like `Range("C3:C" & Rows.Count)`. If you need the range from `C3` to the last non-empty cell, you could use `Range("C3", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` or `Range("C3", Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your working with an Excel Worksheet, this line will do it
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Rows(3).Select